# $V,W$ are linear spaces.$ U_1,U_2$ are subspaces of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V,W$ are linear spaces.$ U_1,U_2$ are sub-spaces of $V$.

Also given, $\dim U_1 = \dim U_2 = 2n$ and there is a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$

also $\dim (U_1 + U_2) = 3n$

prove that: $\dim (T(U_1 \cap U_2)) \le n$

I started by saying that it's obviously $\dim (U_1 \cap U_2) = n$.

but I didn't manage to continue from here.

Comment: Rank-nullity plus playing around with bases.

Comment: Mind posting an answer please?

Comment: In general, $\dim T(V) \leq \dim V$

Comment: Well, yea, but I don't believe it's generally enough as an answer in an exam.

Comment: Yeah, but we're here to render assistance, not always do all the work. I opted for a hint this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank nullity says $\dim im T + \dim \ker T =\dim domain T$

Thus $\dim im T \leq \dim  domain T$
Now we also have

$$\dim (U_1+U_2)=\dim (U_1)+\dim (U_2)-\dim (U_1\cap U_2)$$ and therefor 
$\dim (U_1\cap U_2)=n$
Now for the above remark applied to $T\restriction U_1\cap U_2$ we have 
$$\dim T(U_1\cap U_2)\leq \dim (U_1\cap U_2)=n$$

Comment: I still find it hard to believe what you did here. can you explain a lil better the last sentence?

Comment: Although, generally I do believe it's true what you wrote. no doubt.

Comment: It  follows from the first sentence. Look at T as a transform from $U_1\cap U_2$ the dimension of the image must be only smaller or equal to the dimension od the domain.

Answer (score 2):

First we have
$$\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim U_1+\dim U_2-\dim(U_1\cap U_2)$$
hence we see that
$$\dim(U_1\cap U_2)=n$$
Now we apply the rank-nullity theorem to the restriction  of $T$ to $U_1\cap U_2$ we find the desired result.

Comment: Short and sweet!